# Resize/Scale Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, resize, android-canvas, scale

I have several bitmaps declared in my onCreate.  I'm trying to incrementally increase the size of a "ball" from 1x1 to 100x100 in my onDraw. The following statement works, but of course Eclipse doesn't like it.

```
//Avoid object allocations during draw/layout operations (preallocate and reuse instead) 
ball.set(0, Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(ball.get(0), 20, 20, true));
```

I'm trying to avoid sprite sheets.  Is there a better way?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't really understand your question, do you mean Eclipse has warning "Avoid object allocations during draw/layout operations (preallocate and reuse instead)" for this line of code? If so the easiest way is to follow the instruction given - load and cache the Bitmaps in onCreate or somewhere else.

Comment: I understand the eclipse error message to "preallocate".  I simply want to create the bitmap in the onCreate (as I've done), then resize it in the onDraw (which I've listed above and isn't right)

Comment: The method you are calling is named `createScaledBitmap()` for a reason - it is still creating a Bitmap, in onDraw. So again the solution is to do everything relating to Bitmap creation elsewhere, doesn't matter whether the Bitmap is loaded from APK, scaled from another Bitmap, etc.